# jQuery set session without post

Tags: jquery

```
var date =  new Date();
var date = date.getTimezoneOffset();

timezone=(date*60) * -1;

var gmt = 'GMT';
if (timezone !== 0) {
  gmt += timezone > 0 ? ' +' : ' ';
  gmt += timezone;
}

$(document).ready(function(e) { 
    $.post("tesing.php", {"timezone":timezone});
});
```

How to use jQuery set a session without post?

I use javascript to find out user timezone, i need to create a session timezone, so I can update user's time.

Comment: A session? Or just a Cookie?

Comment: JavaScript is a client-side script. It doesn't have access to session data, which is a **server-side** feature. You'll have to use cookies instead.

Comment: don't like user mess around the cookie

Comment: Well you can use `ajax(get/post)` to post the data to the server and set the `session` variable. but you will need to refresh the page to see its effect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to set the session in your back-end (PHP), you will have to make a request to the testing.php. Either by `POST` or `GET`. If you are implementing a REST API, you can of course use `PUT` as well.